# Is it possible to update part of a named range string in a formula using the value from a variable in another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is an example of a formula I have written:

```
=DatabaseVerName&"."&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4,2,1,TRUE,""&B2&"ChangeLog"))
```

DatabaseVerName is a named range ...It just so happens that the first word in the string (in this case Database), is the value in cell B2. I would like to be able to update the formula so that when I change the value in B2 (say to the word Report) that the formula references the named range "ReportVerName" and not "DatabaseVerName". FWIW, B2 is a a data validated list with 4 options available.

Is this possible and if so how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but something like this might work.

```
=INDIRECT(B3 & "VerName") & "." & INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5,2,1,TRUE,""&B3&"ChangeLog"))
```

So B3 would be equal to "Database" or some other text, and would get concatenated in front of "VerName" to make up the name of a matching named range and then the remaining part of the address, which appears to have been working for you, would be added.

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.  Let us know.